# ImageNet ILSVRC2012 truncated tar archive

Tags: download, tar, imagenet

I have downloaded the image data from ImageNet ILSVRC2012 and save into a hard disk on this site : http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nonpub-downloads . I am working on OSX.
When I do `tar -xvf ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar`, I have this error :

```
x n01729977.tar: Truncated tar archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it ?
I tried to download this synset apart through the website directly but when I re-use `tar -xvf ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar`, I had the same issue.
Thank you

Comment: My first thought is that your transfer failed.  There are 1.2M images in the training set, and 14M in the full set; that's a lot of data for most people.  Can you check the sizes of both source and destination?  If they don't match, then you have a transmission problem.

Comment: Alright, I had a problem so I am going to download it again and then I will check. It must be 138 GB right ? Do you know how to accelerate the downloading ?

Comment: The size we have is 138Gb, yes.  I don't have the exact figure.

Comment: Acceleration depends on where the bottleneck lies.  If it's bandwidth at the server, you can't do much.  If it's bandwidth at your end, you can obtain a faster line (purchase, consult your sysop, etc.).  If you're stuck with the given bandwidth, then look for a source for a compressed file (gz or tz suffix), but note that you'll have to uncompress it (gunzip) on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Prune. Indeed my problem was linked to the downloading. Don't know why it was not fully downloaded. The actual file is 140GB.